# Is there a way with a vaadin 8 custom layout to modify the element class attribute on a parent element?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin8

So with a [Custom Layout](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html) you basically have html. We have this in our template

```html
                    <div id="test-kit-wrap" class="cell cell-above">
                        <div class="sub-cols-wrap">
                            <div id="test-kit" class="cell">
                                <div class="label detail-page-heading">Device/Kit</div>
                                <div location="kit" class="value">Yes</div>
                            </div>
```

We're using templates because of the complexity of this layout. This template currently works except that it's displaying this div when it shouldn't.

What I want to do is add a style to `#test-kit-wrap` that equates to `display: none` when a specific permission is set on the backend. However I can't see a good way to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried nesting two customlayouts and handle the "display" on the server-side?

Comment: @cfrick no, I have not.

Comment: Did you consider making a JS call to change the styling? Something like `document.getElementById('test-kit-wrap').style.setProperty('display', 'none');`

Comment: Yes, though I got concerned about the timing/what to trigger that call on. I did figure out a solution though. Will answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing.

since `#test-kit-wrap` is completely getting display none, then the elements within don't actually matter.

```html
 <div id="test-kit-wrap" class="cell cell-above">
```

So I changed the html from the above, to

```
  <div location="test-kit-wrap" id="test-kit-wrap" class="cell cell-above">
```

and then in my java when I don't want the contents of that element I set an empty `CssLayout` with the class I want, and the correct location. I suspect I could also toggle visibility.

```java
        else {
            String locId = "test-kit-wrap";
            Layout value = new CssLayout();
            value.addStyleName( "hidden" );
            value.setId( locId );
            addComponent( value, locId );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

invoke the following method passing as parameters the layout or one of the ancestors of the layout and "test-kit-wrap"

```
/**
 * Hides the component with given id after searching for it in the given parent.
 */
public static void hideComponentById(Component parent, String id) {
    if (null == parent) {
        return;
    }
    if (null != parent.getId() && parent.getId().equals(id)) {
        parent.setVisible(false);
        return;
    }
    if (HasComponents.class.isAssignableFrom(parent.getClass())) {
        for (Component componentChild : (HasComponents) parent) {
            hideComponentById(componentChild, id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work when the parent I'm hiding is just an html element in the template?

Comment: @xenoterracide if "test-kit-wrap" is not associated to any Vaadin components i suggest you invoke `VerticalLayout hiddenLayout = new VerticalLayout(); hiddenLayout.setVisible(false); yourCustomLayout.addComponent(hiddenLayout, "test-kit-wrap");` instead of the method mentioned in the answer

Comment: ironically, your answer was just reminding me of what I did, and that's basically it, I just answered actually.